# Plugin jQuery Window dá erro de "$ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Estou com o seguinte problema, achei um plugin, [**jQuery Window**](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/),  que abre janelas com botão de minimizar, maximizar, etc, e abre páginas dentro dessa janela, só que não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar.

Gostaria de usar no meu sistema o exemplo número 6, método 2, se alguém puder me dar uma luz de como faço roda como no exemplo que se encontra no site seria ótimo.

Lembrando que eu inclui no meu HTML todas as bibliotecas necessárias como a do jQuery, jQuery UI e do Plugin.

**Código do botão que eu deixei pra chamar a função e abrir a janela quando clicado**

```
<input type='button' value='Click Here to Create Window' onclick='createWindowWithRedirectChecking2();'>
```

**Meu código - Plugin**

```
function createWindowWithRedirectChecking2(){
    $.window({
        title: "create window with redirect checking",
        url: "http://www.myspace.com",
        iframeRedirectCheckMsg: "the window is going to redirect to {url}!!\r\nPlease     select 'cancel' to stay here."
    });
}
```

**Imports**

```
<script src="libs/JQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery-ui-1.10.4/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery-window-5.03/jquery.window.js"></script>

<link href="libs/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link id="jquery_ui_theme_loader" type="text/css" href="libs/jquery-ui-1.10.4/css/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="libs/jquery-window-5.03/css/jquery.window.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

**Código no JSFiddle:**
[JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/JSXKQ/)

Comment: Bem estranho, mas agora que estou vendo sua precedência, experimente definir o Bootstrap como último da lista. Outra coisa... Porquê está usando um versão tão antiga da jQuery? De repente atualizar pode ser um possível caminho.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto alterei agora a ordem como vc sugeriu mas continuou da mesma forma, apenas abre o frame cinza vazio quando clico no botão.

Comment: Isso acontece com qualquer site que você defina?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto se acessar o site do plugin que postei la em cima, da pra ver que lá funciona, e parece até ser simples de implementar, mas na prática aqui comigo n ta funcionando nenhum dos exemplos exibidos la.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto sim, alterei o MySpace que tava ali pelo do uol e apresenta o mesmo resultado, apenas o frame.

Comment: @MarcosJunior Seria possível você passar o seu código para esse site para podermos ver o problema de perto http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Além de passar para o JSFiddle, ainda com a aba **Network** do Chrome aberta, ao clicar no botão você deve ver uma nova entrada de **Method** GET apontando para o URL definido e logo após N outros itens referentes a cada recurso que o site externo requeira. Pra mim o www.myspace.com eu recebo um 301 de **Movido Permanentemente**. Se você tiver algum bloqueio de tráfego, o que é bem improvável, pode aparecer diferente.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha ta ai http://jsfiddle.net/JSXKQ/

Comment: Mas a versão dele é pra lá de antiga. @MarcosJunior, no JSFiddle você não usa <link> e <script>, você carrega recursos no painel à esquerda.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto obg pela dica, nunca usei esse sistema antes.

Comment: Também demorei um pouco a aprender no início, é normal. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nos testes que fiz aqui usando o [código fornecido](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/download/jquery.window.sample.rar) na página do plugin, ele só funciona até o jQuery 1.8.3. A partir do 1.9.0 para de funcionar.

Funciona:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="createWindow();" value="Crefate a window"/>
    <!-- jQuery Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.window.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createWindow() {
            $.window({
                showModal: true,
                modalOpacity: 0.5,
                icon: "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
                title: "Hello World!",
                content: "<h1>Hello World!</h1>",
                footerContent: "<div style='color:gray;'>this is the footer</div>"
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Trocando para `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js` já não funciona.

A [última revisão do plugin](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/js/jquery/window/jquery.window.js) é em 2011:

```
Last Revision: 2011-04-30
```

Acho que é o caso de procurar uma alternativa ou usar o [**jQuery Migrate**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) que permite usar as versões mais novas:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: vou testar aqui no meu ver oq que acontece

Comment: É isso mesmo, só funciona na versão mais antiga do JQuery, muito obrigado brasofilo, e também a todos os outros que ajudaram a solucionar o problema :)

Comment: @MarcosJunior, tem como fazer uma gambiarra oficial ;) Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: vou tentar aqui a gambiarra, obg ;)